# Median of an array column in spark or pandas all rows simultaneously

Tags: pandas, pyspark, median

Strangely enough I cant find any where on the internet if its possible to be done.

I have a datafrme of array column.

```
arr_col
[1,3,4]
[4,3,5]
```

I want result

```
Result
3
4
```

I want the median for each row.

I managed to do it with a pandas udf but it iterates the column and applies  np.median to each row. .

I dont want it as it's slow and tow at a time. I want it to act at all rows the same time.

Either in pandas or pyspark

Answer (score 1):

Use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)

```
import numpy as np
df['Result'] = np.median(np.vstack(df['arr_col']), axis=1)
```

Or [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and [`groupby.median`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.median.html):

```
df['Result'] = (df['arr_col'].explode()
                 .groupby(level=0).median()
                )
```

Output:

```
     arr_col  Result
0  [1, 3, 4]     3.0
1  [4, 3, 5]     4.0
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'arr_col': [[1,3,4], [4,3,5]]})
```

Comment: wow great thnx amazing. Is it really working on the series simultaneously without iteration?

Comment: There is always iteration, one way or another. However, with numpy it occurs at C-speed. Why don't you time the different approaches on your real dataset and give us the feedback?

Comment: Why? That's my question.  I am talking about column iteration here not must be always iteration. For example withcolumn in pyspark doesnt do row at a time. And pandas udf also many times work vectorized without iteration.

Comment: if your approach includes iteration then it doesnt give me any advantage over what I already have. I built a pandas udf with iteration.  But I dont want I want a udf that will act at all rows simultaneously.  Not row at a time. Btw when I try combining you approach in a udf I sometimes get an error for some df it works but not for others not sure why

Comment: now i see you added the explode approach i knew that but i read its way too expensive. S

Comment: Did you time it? Please provide the numbers. The numpy approach is vectorized. `explode` is sometimes quite efficient, you have to test on real data.

Comment: If its vectorized I believe it's not iterating which is good. But I put that into pandas udf and it works only for df that I create on spot. Doesnt work with df that I read from other sources. I try to understand the difference.  The only difference I see is that schema of df I read is nullable =false. Maybe this cant be run on pandas udf not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Can use a udf in pyspark.

```
m =udf(lambda x: int(np.median(x)),IntegerType())
df.withColumn('Result', m(col('arr_col'))).show()

+---+---------+------+
| Id|  arr_col|Result|
+---+---------+------+
|  1|[1, 3, 4]|   3.0|
|  1|[4, 3, 6]|   4.0|
+---+---------+------+
```

Comment: it is also a row at time answer. not what was asked

Comment: What you are looking for does not exist. Iteration happens always where rows or lines of data are involved. Speed will vary depending on method and library used. The alternative is for you to group, find median and explode. That's even more computation  intensive. In fact you end up doing redundant work, finding median and then undoing redundant work dome earlier. Anyway your choice.

Comment: Why iteration always happens? As far as I know there's no iteration in "with column". No iteration in vectorized pandas udf. Your lambda function is looping as if i was my self looping.   I dont want looping I want it to act on each row simultaneously

Comment: Why do you think it must loop? Since each row is independent.  If you have a vector you can increment each value by 1. If you have an array vector why cant the median be calculated at all data at once